# Defining super easy function with python but "missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python

I put 2 arguments like this it said missing 1 required positional argument.
I put 3 arguments it said it requires 2, but 3 were given.

What is the issue with the logic below?

```
def mergeSort(alist,sentence):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
        print(sentence)
        return alist

a=[7,5,4]
mergeSort(a,'Finished')
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly so it can be accurately read.

Comment: The recursive calls are only given one argument, not two.

Answer (score 1):

`mergeSort` takes in two arguments, but you've only given it one argument when you recursively call it in the function body. 
You should change the

```
mergeSort(lefthalf)
mergeSort(righthalf)
```

part to

```
mergeSort(lefthalf, sentence)
mergeSort(righthalf, sentence)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
def mergeSort(alist,sentence):
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf, 'Not finished')
        mergeSort(righthalf, 'Not finished')

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1

    print(sentence)
    return alist

a=[7,5,4] 
mergeSort(a,'Finished')
```

Comment: This is a code dump that makes no attempt to answer OP's question "What is the issue with the logic below?"

Comment: I changed the functions so they do not throw an error: mergeSort(lefthalf, 'Not finished') mergeSort(righthalf, 'Not finished'). I am not sure what you mean.